# submitting sitemap using google-appengine custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I submitted a sitemap using my custom domain name instead of my appspot domain.  It has been a week and I have not been indexed yet.  I have over 2000 pages, so I am not sure if this is normal or not.   I wanted to make sure that I was not supposed to send my appspot domain instead   Does anybody know?  Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any domain you want - Google Search is distinct from Google App Engine. All you can do is wait to be indexed.